# How make my cross to be completely fitted by the surrounding container?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Here the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ishkxp?file=index.js

When you will click on the cross you will see there is remaining space around the cross. I would remove this space.

I would that when I click on the cross the container fit at the maximum the cross instead of letting go remaining space.

I have tried:

> box-sizing: border-box
>   height: auto;
>   absence of width precision to just create content depending of height
>   using a letter instead of an image with font-size to ensure it is the size of the letter that is taken in account.
>   reset button and span styles.
>   play with letter spacing and em.
>   play with display:flex

I am wondering if this is the font that make the component remain with space.

Here my ReactJS' snippet:

```css
.container {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}

.cross {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 4em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<button class="container">
         <span class="cross" >&times;</span>
     </button>
```

Comment: don't rely on font to have shapes, use CSS/SVG to build them because all the font won't behave the same cross borwser/devices/OS

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question your question correctly, you'll want to define a `line-height` for the `.cross`, so that there is less space above and under the cross glyph. Also, prehaps the browser's default `padding` is what causes the unwanted space. So you might want to consider setting `padding: 0` as well.
And `overflow: hidden;` for the `.container`, to make the button adjust to the new height.

```
.container {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden; /* Added */
  padding: 0; /* Added. Removes the browser's default padding of buttons. */
}
.cross {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 4em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: .6; /* Added. Adjust value based on font and glyph. */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

on the span for your cross add the following css:

```
line-height:.5
vertical-align:middle
```